# How to get the average songs practiced per session MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table: `Songs_Practices` with foreign keys for `Song_ID`, `Artist_ID` and `Practice_ID`. I'm trying to get the average amount of songs that each artist practices per practice session. In other words, if we practiced 100 times this year, how many songs did we average per practice. This is what I've tried but keep getting an error. The Count statement that is inside the `AVG()` function returns the correct count, but when placed inside the `AVG()` function I get an error.

```
SELECT AVG(SELECT COUNT( Song_ID ) AS NumberOfSongs
FROM Songs_Practices
WHERE Artist_ID =1
GROUP BY Practice_ID) AS AverageJamsPerPractice
```

I did try to remove the alias 'NumberOfSongs' but that didn't help.

Comment: The subquery will only return a single value, no?!

Comment: When I run the subquery alone I get back 8 rows, which is correct there are 8 practice sessions... with the total number of songs played in each practice... which is what I would expect. That's why I thought I could just average that.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your overall `SELECT` is missing a `FROM...` clause.

Comment: I had tacked a FROM Songs_Practices to the end, but it still through an error.

Comment: Hey Strawberry, Why the link? I don't get it. I provided enough information... I must have, I got an answer in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: @user3498517 could be because you said "I get an error" but didn't say what it was. Sometimes people can answer anyway, and sometimes not. It's always best to specify the error (and what source location your error points to) if you know what it is.

Comment: I mean, if I thought the error was helpful I would have, but it was just a syntax error.... and why not say that to me rather than have me read all that? Seems like it was an unnecessary trolling of my question.. and that seems happens every time I ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there :

```
SELECT AVG(NumberOfSongs)
FROM
(SELECT Practice_ID, COUNT( Song_ID ) AS NumberOfSongs
FROM Songs_Practices
WHERE Artist_ID =1
GROUP BY Practice_ID) t
```

Comment: This just returned 8 rows with 2 columns. One column with the total number of songs in the practice and the other column with the practice ID.

Comment: Yes I didn't know what you want, just need to get rid off the Practice_Id in the main query

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the result of `COUNT()` in the outer query.

```
SELECT AVG(NumberOfSongs) AS AverageJamsPerPractice
FROM
(
     SELECT COUNT( Song_ID ) AS NumberOfSongs
     FROM Songs_Practices
     WHERE Artist_ID =1
     GROUP BY Practice_ID
) AS a
```

Comment: Wow... that worked. I'm a bit confused as to the logic here. But I'll study it and try to wrap my mind around it. I'm rather new to sql statements. Thanks!!!